# Find all positive integers x with dlog(x) = 37/30.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For my first step I know I can reduce it down to dlog(x)=37/3, and I can write it out to be x=2^(a)3^(b)g(c). My goal is to write out the answer in the form of _a+_b+_c = 37. I'm just not sure how to get there from here.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What is the dlog function?

Comment: I think OP means discrete logarithm.

Comment: Your title says $37/30$ but the statement says $37/3$, possibly a typo. Please correct it and also specify if you are using base $3$ etc..

Comment: Or decimal logarithm. As assumption might be natural, or base 2.